# ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute '' for WorkOrder

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pandas, sqlite

I have a rake task that I made, and it should be importing my CSV file that I made by merging 3 CSV files with Pandas and Python (I am new to Ruby and Rails so that's why I used Pandas for that part).

Here is my rake task that I created with `rails generate task import import_csv` which is seen when I run `rake -T`.

```
namespace :import do
  desc "Import finalCsv.csv into database"
  task import_csv: :environment do
    require 'csv'
    filename = "#{Rails.root}/db/finalCsv.csv"
    CSV.foreach(filename, headers: true) do |row|
        WorkOrder.create!(row.to_hash)
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my python script to merge the 3 original CSVs together.

```
import pandas as pd

locations = pd.read_csv("locations.csv")
technicians = pd.read_csv("technicians.csv")
workOrders = pd.read_csv("work_orders.csv")

workOrders = workOrders.merge(technicians, how="inner", left_on="technician_id", right_on="id")
workOrders = workOrders.merge(locations, how="right", left_on="location_id", right_on="id")

workOrders = workOrders.rename(columns={"name_x": "Full Name", "name_y": "Company"})
workOrders = workOrders.drop(labels = ["id_x", "id_y", "id"], axis=1)

finalCsv = workOrders.to_csv("finalCsv.csv", encoding="utf-8")
print(finalCsv)
```

Additionally here are my migration and schema files.

Migration:

```
  def change
    create_table :work_orders do |t|
      t.integer :technician_id
      t.integer :location_id
      t.time :time
      t.integer :duration
      t.integer :price
      t.string :FullName
      t.string :Company
      t.string :City

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Schema:

```
  create_table "work_orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "technician_id"
    t.integer "location_id"
    t.time "time"
    t.integer "duration"
    t.integer "price"
    t.string "FullName"
    t.string "Company"
    t.string "City"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

end
```

Finally, when I run `WorkOrder.all` (my model) or `WorkOrder.new` in the rails console both are valid so I am a little stumped about what is going wrong here.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you're trying to add the attribute `""`. For example, `WorkOrder.new("" => "foo")` should produce the same error.

`WorkOrder.create!(row.to_hash)` check `row`, one of the keys is blank. One of your CSV columns might be missing a header.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV might have extra cells with no headers. If you are 100% positive the data is correct, you can skip the extra data with:

```rb
WorkOrder.create!(row.to_hash.except(''))
```

in the corresponding part of your rake task.

Answer (score 0):

Acknowledgements to everyone. I ended up modifying my Python script so that there was no id column upon writing the Pandas dataframe to a CSV.  I then ran into some unforeseen issues...again and I ended up regenerating my model and starting over.